# Debugging query string values for click once application

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, debugging, clickonce

I am developing a click once aplication. I need to pass some values in the url to the application.

I referred this article [Retrieve Query String from Click Once](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172242%28VS.80%29.aspx) to pass and retrieve the query string values.

How can I pass and debug these query string values in Visual Studio 2008?

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For passing parameters, Go to Project Properties|Publish|Options. Enable "Allow URL parameters to be passed...." there. For including parameters, use [Mage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to change the deployment provider URL once you publish the manifests.

Once the above is done, publish the files on a Test URL using "Debug" build configuration. Once you install the application from there, start it and attach .NET debugger to that process. That way you can debug your deployment

-- Devvrat

Comment: I will try this when I get some time... Any how thanks for answering!! :)